# How can I match all strings unless it contains a certain string?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

So I want to match every string in this list, except the ones that contain the product SKU, which is /s7892632 <---- random string of numbers.  I've been trying to do this for quite some time and have been unsuccessful.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
   /account/login?returnurl=/account/forgotpassword
    /account/login?returnurl=/account/orders
    /account/orders
    /account/updateaddress
    /account/updateemail
    /account/updaterewardscard
    /brands/havaianas
    /careers
    /Category List
    /checkout
    /checkout/addresses
    /checkout/addresses/delivery
    /checkout/addresses/deliverymethod
    /checkout/affilinetbasket
    /checkout/anonymous
    /checkout/confirmation
    /checkout/express
    /checkout/login
    /checkout/login?returnurl=/checkout/addresses
    /checkout/null
    /checkout/payment
    /checkout/paypal
    /checkout/quickshop/
    /checkout/verify
    /click-and-collect
    /click-and-collect/click-and-collect-overview
    /corporate/about-matalan
    /corporate/careers
    /corporate/cookies
    /corporate/history
    /customer-services/accessibility
    /customer-services/contact
    /customer-services/customer-services-home
    /customer-services/delivery
    /customer-services/faq
    /customer-services/fitting-room
    /customer-services/here-to-help
    /customer-services/size-guides
    /delivery
    /events/mothers-day
    /events/mothers-day/s2516241/tassle-detail-slouch-bag
    /events/mothers-day/s2518752/waxed-jacket
    /events/mothers-day/s2519237/fabric-buckle-tote-bag
    /events/mothers-day/s2521182/heart-print-nightie
    /events/mothers-day/s2521184/heart-print-dressing-gown
    /events/mothers-day/s2521185/heart-print-pyjama-set
    /events/mothers-day/s2521679/structured-tote-bag
    /events/mothers-day/s2522143/chiffon-print-dress
    /events/mothers-day/s2522347/butterfly-enamel-bowl-32cm-x-8cm
    /events/mothers-day/s2526013/animal-print-jersey-blazer
    /events/mothers-day/s2527624/croc-tote-bag
    /events/mothers-day/s2529731/shift-dress
    /events/mothers-day?page=1&size=120&cols=4&sort=&id=/events/mothers-day&priceRange[min]=2&priceRange[max]=59
    /events/mothers-day?page=2&size=120&cols=4&sort=&id=/events/mothers-day&priceRange[min]=2&priceRange[max]=59
    /events/mothers-day?page=2&size=36&cols=4&sort=&id=/events/mothers-day&priceRange[min]=2&priceRange[max]=59
    /events/mothers-day?page=3&size=36&cols=4&sort=&id=/events/mothers-day&priceRange[min]=2&priceRange[max]=59
```

Comment: What flavour of regular expressions do you have available?

Comment: ^(?:(?!/s).)*$\r?\n?
^(.(?!\\/s[0-9]{3,}))*$

Comment: Um, that’s not a flavour. Put another way: which language are you using?

Comment: no language - just regular expressions and a tester. its for google analytics. no language ids required

Comment: Your tool which you use for regexp matching has to follow a [specific flavour](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), e.g. PCRE.

Comment: @minitech, according to this page, Google Analytics uses POSIX regular expressions: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034771

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
^(?!.*/s\d{7}/).*
```

Example: http://regexr.com?343nf

This assumes you have each string as a separate element in a list.  If this is actually matching one big string with multiple lines you can use the same regex, but you may need to enable global and multiline options depending on the tool you are using (and make sure dotall/singleline is disabled).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean noSku = !line.matches(".*/s\\d{5,}.*");
```

This uses `{5,}` which allows for any number of digits in the SKU greater than 4 (giving you flexibility with matching). You can change the number to whatever suits.

Answer (score 0):

this matches lines that don't have the code....

```
^((?!s\d{7}).)*$
```